# Trouble with webhook check in self-hosted Supabase/GoTrue for authentication

Tags: docker, authentication, go, supabase, self-hosting

Recently, I attempted to self-host Supabase/GoTrue for authentication purposes. However, I encountered a problem with the webhook check, which prevented me from proceeding. Now, I have a question: Do I need to create a server specifically for the webhook, or am I overlooking something? Additionally, I attempted to create a server, but I haven't received any verification email. It's worth noting that I successfully self-hosted Supabase, and its authentication functionality is working fine without any webhook issues. I'm unsure where I might be making a mistake in the process.
[[Rest client Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMw09.png)][[Logs of gotrue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKO9P.png)]

I tried creating server for the webhook and failed cause it was not sending verification email and its logs in automatically. I just want to run supabase/gotrue successfully so what do I have to do like create server for webhook or supabase/gotrue already contains it.

ps: I tried creating server in nodejs for webhook but not getting verification email and also login automatically and I'm also new to golang.

Comment: What webhook are you talking about? GoTrue is an inherited project, and there is some existing webhook support but it's not part of Supabase Auth and not maintained. The team is working on an alternative.